# How to inject complete propertiesfile in a springbean

Tags: spring, resources, properties-file

I have a properties-file with a lot of values and I do not want to list them in my bean-configuration-file separately. E.g.:

```
<property name="foo">
    <value>${foo}</value>
</property>
<property name="bar">
    <value>${bar}</value>
</property>
```

and so on.

I imagine to inject all completely as `java.util.Properties` or less as a `java.util.Map`.
Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 19):

For Java config you can use something like this:

```
@Autowired @Qualifier("myProperties")
private Properties myProps;

@Bean(name="myProperties")
public Properties getMyProperties() throws IOException {
    return PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(
        new ClassPathResource("/myProperties.properties"));
}
```

You can also have multiple properties this way, if you assign a unique bean name (`Qualifier`) to each instance.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you can use `<util:properties>` to load a properties file and declare the resulting `java.util.Properties` object as a bean. You can then inject that as you would any other bean property.

See [section C.2.2.3 of the Spring manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-properties), and their example:

```
<util:properties id="myProps" location="classpath:com/foo/jdbc-production.properties"
```

Remember to declare the `util:` namespace as per [these instructions](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util).

Comment: Treat is like anyother bean. Use it within xml config using `ref=myProps` or Autowire a Properties to let Spring take care of it for you.

Answer (score 11):

For Java Config, use `PropertiesFactoryBean`:

```
@Bean
public Properties myProperties() {
    PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    propertiesFactoryBean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("/myProperties.properties"));
    Properties properties = null;
    try {
        propertiesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        properties = propertiesFactoryBean.getObject();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.warn("Cannot load properties file.");
    }
    return properties;
}
```

And then, set the properties object:

```
@Bean
public AnotherBean myBean() {
    AnotherBean myBean = new AnotherBean();
    ...

    myBean.setProperties(myProperties());

    ...
}
```

Hope this helps for those interested in Java Config way.

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of code. Isn't there an easier way like the 1-liner XML config `<util:properties ...>`?

Comment: @rustyx oh! I didn't find at that time any other way to do it, but [yours](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31193653/787375) is very nice! :)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible with the `PropertyOverrideConfigurer` mechanism:

```
<context:property-override location="classpath:override.properties"/>
```

Properties file:

```
beanname1.foo=foovalue
beanname2.bar.baz=bazvalue
```

The mechanism is explained in the section [3.8.2.2 Example: the PropertyOverrideConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-overrideconfigurer)

Comment: thanks for your answer - my fault, the properties-file will be edited by a "not-developer" and shall be "easy to read" for the editor with no special background. Thus, names of beans wouldn't be the right way to use as key.

Answer (score 0):

This is an echo of [@skaffman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21234/skaffman)'s response in this SO question. I am adding more details to help others and myself when I try to solve this in the future.

There are three ways to inject the property file

## Method 1

```
<bean id="myProps" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:com/foo/jdbc-production.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Reference ( [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22024298/1799502) )

## Method 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    ...
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="...
    ...
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd"/>
    <util:properties id="myProps" location="classpath:com/foo/jdbc-production.properties"/>
```

Reference ( [link](https://lova4java.blogspot.com/2013/06/spring-collections-using-util-xml-tags.html) )

## Method 3

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:com/foo/jdbc-production.properties" />
</bean>
```

Reference ( [link](https://coderanch.com/t/553315/frameworks/access-properties-file-values-Spring#2510415) )

Essentially, all the methods can create a `Properties` bean out of the properties file. You may even directly inject a value from the property file by using `@Value` injector

```
@Value("#{myProps[myPropName]}")
private String myField;
```