# Load multiple properties file using <util:properties> in spring 3

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want to load multiple properties files using `<util:properties>` tag in a spring 3 application.
I searched on the blogs, but cannot get the correct path to do this.

Hopefully somebody give me the answer to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My solution

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:*.properties,file:/some/other/path/*.properties" />
```

Comment: This works for the placeholder that you have in your config file ${some.props}, but that does not work with @Value("#{properties}") in your bean, to use that solution that @Alexei Osipov works, just in case someone need that information

Answer (score 24):

Actually `<util:properties>` is just convenient tag for `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean`. And `PropertiesFactoryBean` does support multiple locations.

So it is possible to create bean with `Properties` this way:

```xml
    <bean id="myProps" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:myprops-common.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:myprops-override.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:some-more-props-here.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 3):

util:properties seems to support only 1 properties file ([reference](http://develop.nydi.ch/2010/12/spring-multiple-properties/)). You might want to use the configuration suggested by @peperg.